# pass result of annotation work to annotated method

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, aspect

Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Multipart {

    Class acceptClass();

}
```

Annotated method:

```
@Multipart (acceptClass = SomeClass.class)
public void someMethod(SomeClass a){
  //do stuff..
}
```

MultipartAspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MultipartAspect {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(Multipart)", argNames = "multipart")
    public void before(JoinPoint jp, Multipart multipart) {}

    @Before("before()")
    public SomeClass doStuffBeforeThing() {
       SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(); //object of passed class
       //do something..
       return sc;                      //return this to annotated method(somemethod)
    }

}
```

I want before method works execute annotation, create object of passed class(`SomeClass`) and the pass object of this class to annotated method. Could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use @Around advice instead of @Before.